# Get/Set for a Private Static Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

I've defined a class with the following property:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Job> allJobs;
```

Access is defined as follows:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allJobs;
        }
        set
        {
            this.allJobs = value;
        }
    }
```

The get set works fine when I assign a whole ObservableCollection to the property, the set works fine for retrieving it obviously. But why have I lost all the methods that normally allow me to 'Add' (i.e. add 1 job to the collection)?

At the moment I'm having to create a temporary collection to populate to then assign to the allJobs property and I shouldn't have to.

Any ideas??

Comment: Note, that property is supposed to read as "ObservableCollection<Job>", don't know what happened to the "<Job>" bit.

Comment: What do you mean lost? You can't go `AllJobs.Add(newItem)`??

Comment: The collection in code is private but NOT static. What is all about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean with 'lost methods'? Have you tried AllJobs.Add()? The following code works for me:

```
void Main()
{
    AllJobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
    AllJobs.Add(new Job());
}

public class Job { }

private ObservableCollection<Job> allJobs;

public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
{
    get
    {
        return this.allJobs;
    }
    set
    {
        this.allJobs = value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment I've amended my code as follows but everything still works for me, I have noticed however that you don't seen to initialise the allJobs collection anywhere.

```
void Main()
{
    PresentationManager.Instance.AllJobs.Add(new Job());
}

public class Job { }

sealed class PresentationManager 
{ 
    public static readonly PresentationManager Instance = new PresentationManager(); 

    private PresentationManager()
    {
        allJobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Job> allJobs; 
    public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs 
    { 
        get { return this.allJobs; } 
        set { this.allJobs = value; } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The difference between our code is that I'm using singleton instantiation, I should've probably mentioned that:
    sealed class PresentationManager
    {
        public static readonly PresentationManager Instance = new PresentationManager();

        private ObservableCollection<Job> allJobs;

public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
        {
            get
            {
                return this.allJobs;
            }
            set
            {
                this.allJobs = value;
            }
        }
}

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: What error message do you get when you try it? Saying it doesn't work is much better with an error message. :)

Comment: @DanielMcNulty so go `PresentationManager.Instance.AllJobs.Add(newItem)`

Comment: Yes that's the exact line of code I have written in the 'main' method Ray. It doesn't like it, there are no error messages, it's just stops executing the rest of the code in the load method, it doesn't actually break it tho. The app doesn't crash!?

Comment: BTW apologies for my use of code formatting and commenting here, it's the first thread I've made.

Comment: Do you have any try/catch code around it? I have noticed that you never seem to set the allJobs collection to a valid collection - you might have a null-reference exception being caught somewhere.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty - Edit your question with the new code. Comments are meant for people to *request* more information. That information should be edited into the question or answer, not supplied as a new comment.

Comment: J.Kommer nailed it with that answer. Thanks a lot mate. Thanks for everyone's help, appreciated.

Comment: Ok Chris I'll bear it in mind for next time. I'd add to your rep J.Kommer but I can't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you wouldn't want a setter for such a property, as you would lose all events bound to the ObservableCollection when the setter is used.

`public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs { get; private set; }`

Comment: It's acting strange this, the code breaking on the line that I'm adding to the collection but even in debugging mode is not lettin me know about any sort of exception being thrown. I'm gonna have to come back and make a thread when I've got more specifics because this is baffling me.

Comment: An excellent point and getting a +1 from me despite not technially being an answer to the question. :)

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: Show us the line where you are adding that is breaking on and we may be able to shed some additional light on things...

Comment: Job job5 = new Job();
job5.Task= "ToDoSomething";
PresentationManager.Instance.AllJobs.Add(job1);